# Find one entity from database table in TypeORM

Tags: node.js, express, typeorm

I am using TypeORM in my express.js project.

I wonder in TypeORM, how can I find an entity from database without providing any condition, I just need to get one instance from database table.

For example, I have a `students` table which maps to `Student` entity. I tried:

```
const student = await Student.find()[0];
```

But it is not working. Any suggestion?

P.S. after I found a student I need to access its id e.g. `const sid = student.id`

I am using the `sid` to construct a data as a payload for response. e.g. `const payload={'student_id': sid, ...}`

Comment: You can try `const student = await Student.findOne({})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using findOne method by passing empty object as argument.

```
const student = await Student.findOne({})
```

You can also use your current approach but you gotta make sure you wrap your await in parentesis before you access the array index.

```
const student = (await Student.find())[0];
```

Beware though, find() will read all of the database while findOne() will only be a single read.

**Update**
To avoid type issues , you can add a type guard.

```
if(!student){
  // return or send error as response.
return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. When I try to access the id of the found object `student.id` I get error "Object is possibly undefined", how to get rid of this error?

Comment: You can access the value using optional chaining `student?.id`. You should also consider moving whole block in a `try/catch` in case promise resolution fails.

Comment: Tried your suggestion but get error `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'MultipartValue'`, could you please update your answer with a proper way to access a field of the found `student` for example, student.id

Comment: Please add the relevant code,on how you are using the `student` value.

Comment: No i meant , how are you using the sid? What function are you calling on it? You need to add a type guard wherever you are using it to filter out undefined values.

Comment: I updated again, I am using the id to construct a object for my test. Yes, I tried type guard code but it throws errors that's why I wonder if you could provide code examples of how to properly accessing the student's id.

Comment: I just posted an example

Comment: No problem.Happy to help